# Can I apply effects directly on my FireStudio Project?

Tags: audio-recording, effects

I have 6 mics plugged into my FireStudio Project audio interface.  I like the zero-latency monitoring available by plugging headphones into the interface, but I can't add simple effects, like reverb.  If I want to hear effects while monitoring, I have to plug the headphones into my computer.  Is there a way to apply effects directly on the FireStudio, so I can still use its outputs for monitoring?  I read a little about sends and returns, which (i think) route the audio through an effects device, but is there a way to do this without additional hardware?  What's the actual term for applying effects directly on an audio interface?

Comment: are you going to edit it with a DAW or only with FireStudio? If the first is the case then the answer is obvious, apply effects to each channel. If only FireStudio then the answer is no. Since the FireStudio doesn't have any built in FX, you have no other options than additional outboard effects or without using a DAW. And there isn't any term for applying effects. An effect is technically called a sound effect but I haven't never heard anything like what you are describing.

Comment: the software that comes with it, a DAW, has built in effects and virtual instruments apparently. But how you are describing it as hardware only, this is not possible. Studio One Artist Recording Software is the name of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply audio effects with zero latency and no external hardware.

Your Presonus has insert connectors for channel 1 and 2 on the back for external hardware. That is probably what you should use.